# Rails undefined method 'to_i'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When the user creates a new worequest, I want to set the worequest.statuscode_id to the first entry in the statuscodes table.

The following (from worequest.rb) was working in Rails 3.1 but now I've upgraded to 3.2, it's not working.

```
    after_initialize :defaults

      def defaults
        self.statuscode_id ||= Statuscode.first
      end
```

I get

```
undefined method `to_i' for #<Statuscode:0x007fe934b67bd0>
```

Any idea why this doesn't work now?  Do you know something that will work?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us more code here? What does the Statuscode class look like?

Comment: Is `Statuscode` relation 1..n? If yes, why are you not using `statuscode` instead?

Comment: I changed self.statuscode_id to self.statuscode -- and it worked !  Thanks Niemier.  If you want to enter an answer, I will accept it.